# How to fix HTTP Error 500.19 in IIS when browsing web site?

Tags: asp.net-core

I developed a project with asp.net core 5 and angular 15. the backend and frontend parts are in separate folders.I want to publish and deploy the project as a single unit on the local host. Therefore, I built frontend part and copied it in wwwroot folder of backend part and then published the project. This is the content of **web.config** of the published application:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\serverApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Then, I add website in the IIS version 10.0.22000.708, and set the physical path of the publish folder during the website creation.But I get a **500.19** error with code **0x8007000d** when I browse the website. On the other hand, when I click on any of the IIS modules related to the website, I get a **web.config** error and no details are displayed as shown in the figure below:

[image: Screenshot of IIS]

Even in the **turn Windows features on or off** and also in the **Application Development Features** of windows 11, I added some tools and ASP features, but the problem still remains. Of course, I don't know if the ASP.NET modules I added are needed or not.
I searched a lot about this error and couldn't find a solution. I would be grateful if you could provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: There are a lot of causes for this error.  I would first check to be sure the .NET-Core hosting bundle is installed.   (You need to download/install it...) There are a bunch of different threads on here about the error.  With many different solutions listed.

Comment: As you suggested, I installed the Hosting bundle v.7.0.4, and then restarted IIS. An error is given when the Handler Mapping in the IIS is clicked. On the other hand, when browsing the website, error 500.19 with code 0x80070021 is given. Also the Config error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: To fix the above error, I enabled the features. I checked all but CGI in the Application Development Features. But I got another error: Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in its module list. Is this error related to the incompatibility of the version of Hosting bundle v.7.0.4 with Asp.net core 5 or not?

Comment: Don't really know... my web.config file does not have a "<handlers>" section.  One thing to try would be to publish as self-contained.  That would rule out any run-time compatibility problems.

Comment: ...scratch that I do have <handlers> in my published/deployed version (not local development version)  My deployed web.config looks exactly like yours.  I believe I'm still using 3.1 version of the .net core hosting bundle, though.  (I've been afraid to update it...)  I'm currently at .net6 for my code/run-time, but 3.1 for .net hosting bundle.  I can say that whenever I saw this error, the solution never involved changing the web.config file.  It was always some other server configuration.

Comment: Maybe check this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules